# How to make remote X access to Linux Mint 18 more reliable

Tags: linux-mint, xorg

I have a machine, which I'll refer to as RS (remove server) which is running Linux Mint 18.3.  It has a suite of desktop apps installed, including LibreOffice, Chrome, Eclipse, etc.

I have another machine, which I'll refer to as PC (it's my personal computer) which I'm using as a thin client to access apps and data on RS.  I want to keep the apps and data separate between the two, with no chance of data from RS ending up on PC.  Incidentally, PC is also running a version of Linux Mint.

I have XRDP installed on RS.  I try to avoid using it, though.  I want to let my PC do all the GUI stuff, reducing RAM / CPU usage on RS, such that the tasks I'm running on it (such as building code) have more resources available.

RS and PC are connected via a Gb Ethernet switch; little else is on that switch.  So there's plenty of bandwidth and little to worry for security between the two.

If I tell PC

```
sudo xhost +
```

then connect into RS and tell it to run xterm with a -display variable that points to the IP address of my PC, I get an xterm window on PC, from which I can run apps (including GUI apps like the aforementioned LibreOffice and Chrome); the apps are running on RS but I'm "driving" them from PC.

I am NOT tunneling this through an SSH connection; that just eats CPU and slows down the connectivity.  See the earlier part of about the switch and associated network isolation.

If I spend an hour or so working with Chrome or LO, and don't interact with the xterm, though, it freezes (no longer accepting any input) and ultimately dies.  If I have an xterm running something (tailing the logs of a long-running task, for example), that never dies; it works as long as there's output going to it.

If I spend an hour so working with LO and ignore Chrome, it will freeze and, ultimately die.

Obviously, this is quite annoying.  I'll spend an hour+ working on something, then need to go restart some of my apps.

If I've not used gvim for a while, when it starts I see a bunch of messages about:

```
(gvim:6759): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-yYgGVJw8L6: Connection refused
```

After starting / using / closing  gvim a few times, that message will cease to appear and gvim will work normally.

It sounds like DBUS or some other task is "timing out" and killing stuff, because of inactivity.   I don't know enough about DBUS, though, to determine if that's what's happening or if something else is going on.

Whatever is going on, I'd like to configure RS such that it doesn't "timeout" such processes, letting them run for as long as I want them to.

As mentioned earlier, RS has XRDP installed.  If I run it, then use Remmina on PC to access it, apps never "die" and I never see the DBUS messages when kicking off gvim.  But I'm using much more RAM / CPU on RS, causing a noticeable reduction in performance.

I'm open to suggestions on how to troubleshoot this further and, hopefully, fix this issue.

Comment: If you have an "answer" then post it as an answer, not as an edit to your question. [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been over 18 months since I posted this question. No one has commented with any suggestions. I will attempt to answer my question with what else I've learned in the meantime, in case someone else has a similar problem.

In my case, the Remote Server is a Linux VM running on Hyper-V. The VM's only connection is to a VPN client which dynamically-assigns the IP address.

Some of you may be slapping your forehead at this point.

For those who haven't been blinded by the light, PC is connecting to RS (the VM) via its IP address.

Every hour or so, the VPN client re-authenticates and either renews its lease on the IP address (in which case, everything keeps working just fine) or gets a new IP address (in which case, PC loses its connection to RS and everything dies).

If I'm using RDP to connect to XRDP, it manages to renew the lease, so the IP address doesn't change.

While functioning a a thin client, I've had it kill everything while I was in the middle of using Eclipse, so actual use vs timeout is not the issue. Because it doesn't change the IP address each hour, I didn't see the correlation until looking at the logs on the VPN client.

When using Gvim, it appears that it attempts to cache the last known IP address and attempts to connect to DBUS on that IP address, instead of using localhost. Consequently, the first few times I try to use Gvim, it tries to hit DBUS on the old IP address and I get the error message. After a while, it gets the message, connects with the correct (current) IP address and the error message ceases.

I never had this problem when I was using a VirtualBox-based VM, previously. But the VirtBox VM used a static IP address and the Windows host machine shared its VPN connection with that address. Because the IP address never changed, this system worked reliably.

If I can figure out how to get Hyper-V to do something similar, this setup should become reliable.